# No suitable user-defined conversion from std::shared_ptr to std::shared_ptr exists

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, static-cast

I'm trying to cast `std::shared_ptr<Node>` to `std::shared_ptr<Node3D>`

```
auto node3d = static_cast<std::shared_ptr<Node3D>>(node);
```

I got an error:

`E0312  no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::shared_ptr<Node>" to "std::shared_ptr<Node3D>" exists`

Comment: You'd improve your question by far if you gave more context, like a [mcve]. In particular, the relation between `Node` and `Node3D` is missing.

Comment: This is sort of a duplicate but the title uses downcast which thwarts folks finding it.

Answer (score 2):

Try `std::static_pointer_cast`

```
std::static_pointer_cast<Node3D>(node)
```